# Is there a JDK in the Android device for an AIR app to access it via NativeProcess?

Tags: android, air

What where is it, and does it change location between the different Android versions?

Answer (score 1):

Even though you're developing Android Apps using the Java language as the syntax, the actual Android device never sees this code (and even if real Java code was executed on Android, no [Java Development Kit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) would be necessary because the [Java Runtime Environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Runtime_Environment) is sufficient).

Android-Apps are executed on the [Dalvik VM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_VM).

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Would this mean that I can run any .jar application with no JDK, but simply by accessing the Android OS of the device.

Comment: As described: there is no Java VM on Android, so no. Only the syntax is Java!